JS convert PDF into blob
function generatePDF() {
    var pdfObject = jsPDFInvoiceTemplate.default(props);
    var blob = pdfObject.OutputType(blob);
    var csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('pdfData', blob);
    // Send PDF data to Laravel controller for saving
    $.ajax({
        url: '/save-pdf',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false, // Don't set contentType manually, let jQuery handle it
        processData: false, // Don't process the data, let jQuery handle it
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // Handle success response
            console.log('PDF saved successfully. PDF ID:', response.pdfId);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // Handle error response
            console.error('Error saving PDF:', error);
        }
    });
    console.log(blob);
}

Error pdfObject.OutputType(blob) appear when using this javascript. I need to get the pdfObject (generated PDF) and send into the php where the file will be stored into database. When I debug the program, the issue is that the blob format is not generated hence no data is passed then the insert process error.
I tried the var blob ="testing data";  and everythings works fine and perfect

short answer, as per the documentation, you should find your blob under pdfObject.blob
jsPDF : A library to generate PDFs in JavaScript ( documentation )
npm : jspdf-invoice-template
i always like to include a working code example


<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-invoice-template@latest/dist/index.js"></script>

<script>

        var props   = getprops();
        
        var pdf     = jsPDFInvoiceTemplate.default(props);
        
        console.log(pdf.blob);

        
        var window_url     = URL.createObjectURL(pdf.blob);
        window.open(window_url);

        
        /*

        (async()=>{

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file",pdf.blob);
        
            var res   = await fetch('/upload',{method:'post',body:formData});
            var txt   = await res.text();
            console.log(txt);

        })();
        
        */
  


        function getprops(){
        
              return {
                    outputType: 'blob',
                    returnJsPDFDocObject: true,
                    fileName: "Invoice 2021",
                    orientationLandscape: false,
                    compress: true,
                    logo: {
                        src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edisonneza/jspdf-invoice-template/demo/images/logo.png",
                        type: 'PNG', //optional, when src= data:uri (nodejs case)
                        width: 53.33, //aspect ratio = width/height
                        height: 26.66,
                        margin: {
                            top: 0, //negative or positive num, from the current position
                            left: 0 //negative or positive num, from the current position
                        }
                    },
                    stamp: {
                        inAllPages: true, //by default = false, just in the last page
                        src: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edisonneza/jspdf-invoice-template/demo/images/qr_code.jpg",
                        type: 'JPG', //optional, when src= data:uri (nodejs case)
                        width: 20, //aspect ratio = width/height
                        height: 20,
                        margin: {
                            top: 0, //negative or positive num, from the current position
                            left: 0 //negative or positive num, from the current position
                        }
                    },
                    business: {
                        name: "Business Name",
                        address: "Albania, Tirane ish-Dogana, Durres 2001",
                        phone: "(+355) 069 11 11 111",
                        email: "email@example.com",
                        email_1: "info@example.al",
                        website: "www.example.al",
                    },
                    contact: {
                        label: "Invoice issued for:",
                        name: "Client Name",
                        address: "Albania, Tirane, Astir",
                        phone: "(+355) 069 22 22 222",
                        email: "client@website.al",
                        otherInfo: "www.website.al",
                    },
                    invoice: {
                        label: "Invoice #: ",
                        num: 19,
                        invDate: "Payment Date: 01/01/2021 18:12",
                        invGenDate: "Invoice Date: 02/02/2021 10:17",
                        headerBorder: false,
                        tableBodyBorder: false,
                        header: [
                          {
                            title: "#", 
                            style: { 
                              width: 10 
                            } 
                          }, 
                          { 
                            title: "Title",
                            style: {
                              width: 30
                            } 
                          }, 
                          { 
                            title: "Description",
                            style: {
                              width: 80
                            } 
                          }, 
                          { title: "Price"},
                          { title: "Quantity"},
                          { title: "Unit"},
                          { title: "Total"}
                        ],
                        table: Array.from(Array(10), (item, index)=>([
                            index + 1,
                            "There are many variations ",
                            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text dummy text ",
                            200.5,
                            4.5,
                            "m2",
                            400.5
                        ])),
                        additionalRows: [{
                            col1: 'Total:',
                            col2: '145,250.50',
                            col3: 'ALL',
                            style: {
                                fontSize: 14 //optional, default 12
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            col1: 'VAT:',
                            col2: '20',
                            col3: '%',
                            style: {
                                fontSize: 10 //optional, default 12
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            col1: 'SubTotal:',
                            col2: '116,199.90',
                            col3: 'ALL',
                            style: {
                                fontSize: 10 //optional, default 12
                            }
                        }],
                        invDescLabel: "Invoice Note",
                        invDesc: "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary.",
                    },
                    footer: {
                        text: "The invoice is created on a computer and is valid without the signature and stamp.",
                    },
                    pageEnable: true,
                    pageLabel: "Page ",
              };
            
        }//getprops

  
</script>



jsbin - working example
jsbin will block the popup, it should be accessible ( one time only ) by clicking the address bar icon


i include some additional details for convenience
to upload to and from a nodejs server the following code can be used
<!-- browser.html -->

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-invoice-template@latest/dist/index.js"></script>

<script type=module>

        var props   = getprops();   //  use function from above
        
        var pdf     = jsPDFInvoiceTemplate.default(props);
        
        var res   = await fetch('http://localhost:3050/upload',{method:'post',body:pdf.blob});
        var txt   = await res.text();
        console.log(txt);

</script>

this is a simple nodejs server, http only for brevity, cors enabled
//server.js

      var fs        = require('fs');
      var http      = require('http');
      var server    = http.createServer(req).listen(3050);
      
      console.log('http://localhost:3050');

      
      function req(req,res){
      
            console.log(req.url,req.method);
            
            var headers = {
                'access-control-allow-origin'     : '*',
                'access-control-allow-methods'    : 'options,post,get',
                'access-control-allow-headers'    : 'content-type'
            };
        
            if(req.method==='OPTIONS'){
                res.writeHead(204,headers);
                res.end();
                return;
            }

            if(req.url.endsWith('upload')){
                var fd    = fs.createWriteStream('example.pdf');
                req.pipe(fd);
                res.writeHead(200,headers);
                res.end('ok');
                return;
            }
            
            console.log('send pdf');
            
            var fd    = fs.createReadStream('example.pdf');
            res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'application/pdf'});
            fd.pipe(res);
              
      }//req

after uploading the pdf, open a new browser window at http://localhost:3050/ and you should see your pdf

The blob file do appended into the database but the content seems not in the original PDF content. Instead the content of the blob file is just some C::AppData\temp location something like that

your question didnt mention a database, its working on my end, do you have nodejs? which database are you using?

Im using phpmyadmin as my database
